# Android Studio can't find file

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I added my signing keys into `keys` folder in root of the project:

```
.\

   keys\
       sign.properties
   src\
       main\
   build.gradle
```

I added next lines to my build script:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        Properties p = new Properties()
        p.load(new FileInputStream('keys/sign.properties'))

        storeFile file(p.file)
        storePassword p.password
        keyAlias p.alias
        keyPassword p.keyPassword
    }
}
```

The command line gradle build is able to assemble build. However Android Studio gives me error that file `sign.properties` is not found.

How to point AS to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a problem with what the working directory is when compiling on the command line vs. compiling from Android Studio. I see a discrepancy there that I need to investigate further and possibly file a bug for. In any event, it's better to be explicit about nailing down the path to prevent confusion.

Try this:

```
p.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file('keys/sign.properties')))
```

This will nail down the file to be relative to the *project* (not the *module*) root, which is also where the `settings.gradle` file lives.

**EDIT**

I filed bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64018 for this. The workaround I showed you above should do nicely, and is maybe a best practice in any event.

Comment: Thank you for helping and firing the issue

Comment: I added comment to the issue "I don't mind to use `rootProject` but why compile dependency from file works perfectly `compile files('libs/MixpanelAPI.jar')`? I prefer to have consistent behaviour"

Comment: I suspect the implementations in the plugin aren't consistent. The `files` function mustn't be dependent on the working directory the way arbitrary Groovy script is.

Comment: in `compile files('libs/MixpanelAPI.jar')` the method `files()` is the same as `file()`. Both of them are method on the project object and work based on relative path to the project. One returns a file, the other a file collection.