# Debugging failed Gradle builds in Android studio

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have the following simple build configuration with a task:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    task compileSass(type:Exec) {
        commandLine 'sass', "src/main/theme/default.scss", "src/main/assets/default.css"
    }

    project.afterEvaluate{
        preBuild.dependsOn("compileSass")
    }
}
```

The build runs just fine when run from the command line with `gradle installDebug` but fails when running from Android Studio with the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':PixateTest:compileSass'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'sass''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

How can I pass the parameters, such as --stacktrace, from Android Studio to Gradle so I can debug why the task fails?

Answer (score 8):

On OSX: Android Studio -> Preferences -> Compiler -> Gradle -> Command-line Options

Comment: In the current Android Studio on Windows it's: *File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler -> Command-line options*

Answer (score 3):

File > Settings > Gradle > Gradle VM options.

I suspect you're failing compileSass because of "sass" not being on PATH.

Comment: That's correct, the working directory isn't the same when you run from Android Studio. Rather than using environment variables, it's better to use the Gradle DSL to construct paths relative to your project; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731974/android-studio-cant-find-file/20733437#20733437 for inspiration.

Comment: Yeah, probably was a path problem. I was starting Android Studio from the dock, once I started it from the shell it started working.