# Running gradle with options in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, stack-trace

How do I run Gradle with options in Android Studio? I get the message

> There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib:
>   Parameterized type
>   `com.googlecode.objectify.Key<com.busy.mycloud.db.Dog>` not supported.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

So how do I run it with the option?

Comment: Check this: [Debugging failed Gradle builds in Android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423373/debugging-failed-gradle-builds-in-android-studio)

Comment: Funny the stack trace does not tell me where in my code the error occurred. All the trace is Google stuff such as `com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JsonConfigWriter`